# strict monotonicity definition in Reny textbook and strong monotonicity

Tags: microeconomics, consumer-theory, preferences, definition

[Reny-advanced microeconomic theory-page 10](http://zalamsyah.staff.unja.ac.id/wp-content/uploads/sites/286/2019/11/1-Advanced-Microeconomic-Theory-3rd-Ed.-JEHLE-RENY.pdf)

[wiki-monotonicity preference](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Monotone_preferences)

[image]

This capture is the definition of strict monotonicity in Reny's textbook, and I've compare it with wikipedia also other textbook *Felix Munoz-Garcia-Advanced Microeconomic Theory*, they are different. Does strict monotonicity and strong monotonicity are different concept or **is this Reny's definition wrong?**

Comment: Wikipedia does not define strict monotoniciy there. What would it mean for a definition to be wrong?

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker Thank you for your reply. isn't strict monotonicity the same thing as strong monotonicity?

Comment: Definitions do vary from text to text. Also, given continuity, the first part of the definition used by Jehle and Reny is redundant. I don’t think it is "wrong" though.